# How to delete or omit keys from a JSON file?

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file with many parameters from which I want to extract their information (their keys and values) in my python script (ipynb). But I don´t need all of these parameters because not all of them are currently in use.
The json file looks like this (but with many more parameters):

```
{"tech_water": { 
  "name": "Water",
  "value": 0.80,
  "description": "",
  "distribution": "normal",
  "arguments": {
    "mu": 0.20,
    "sigma": 0.02
  }
}, 
"mc_index": {
  "name": "index mc",
  "value": 1,
  "description": "not in use",
  "distribution": "uniform",
  "arguments": {
    "lower": 1,
    "upper": 500
 } } }
```

The parameter I want to omit/skip here is: "mc_index"

My code looks like this:
first my problem definition:

```
problem = {
    'num_vars': 3,
    'names': [],
    'dists': [],
    'bounds': []
}
```

Then I want to loop through my parameters and skip mc_index. For that I tried this:

```
invalid = {"humidity_PET", "mc_index"}
def excluded_parameters(d, parameters):
   return {x: d[x] for x in d if x not in parameters}

   for parameter in excluded_parameters(json_load.items(), invalid):
      if 'distribution' and 'arguments' in parameter:
          problem['names'].append(parameter['name'])
          problem['dists'].append(parameter['distribution'])
          problem['bounds'].append(parameter['arguments'])
          
         
         print(parameter['name'], parameter['distribution'], parameter['arguments'])
```

and the output is now:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
path in <cell line: 7>()
      4 def excluded_parameters(d, parameters):
      5    return {x: d[x] for x in d if x not in parameters}
----> 7 for parameter in excluded_parameters(json_load.items(), invalid): 
      9    if 'distribution' in parameter:
     10       problem['names'].append(parameter['name'])

path' in excluded_parameters(d, parameters)
      4 def excluded_parameters(d, parameters):
----> 5    return {x: d[x] for x in d if x not in parameters}

c:\Users\karen\Documents\Uni_Letztes_Semester_WS21_22\Masterarbeit_ICTV\gsa-revolpet\MyFirstAnacondaNotebook.ipynb Cell 68' in <dictcomp>(.0)
      4 def excluded_parameters(d, parameters):
----> 5    return {x: d[x] for x in d if x not in parameters}

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

I didn´t use the del keyword because it was not right. I don´t want to delete the key from the json file, only to skip or not read them in the python nb, in case those parameters will be used in the future.

**I expect the output to look like this:**
`water normal {'mu':0.2, 'sigma': 0.02}`
i.e. with the respective name, distribution and arguments.

and without parameter:
`index mc uniform {'lower': 1, 'upper': 500}`

Comment: If you want to delete a key k from a dictionary d the syntax is `del d[k]`, I'm not sure if this will help you.

Comment: also your if condition has a bug. it should be `if k1 in d and k2 in d` i believe.

Comment: @mkrieger1 thank you, I tried it but it still doesn´t work. I tried to make a new for-loop:
``` for parameter in json_load.values():
   del parameter['humidity_PET']
   print(parameter['name'], parameter['distribution'], parameter['arguments']) ````

and the error is: KeyError: 'humidity_PET'
and without the ' ', the error is: NameError: name 'humidity_PET' is not defined

Comment: I think I might have something that could help you. But, can you update your question with what you expect the final result to look like. I'm taking a guess, but is this an example of a final output? `{"Water": {"distribution": "uniform", "arguments": {"lower": 1, "upper": 500}}}`

Comment: @idjaw, thanks, I updated what I expect as an output!

Comment: @Karen your output doesn't necessarily match something valid. Can you look at my previous response and see if the example I put was what you are looking for? If not, can you make your expected output a more valid python data structure? The closest guess I can make is that you are just looking for a list that is this: `[water, normal, {'mu':0.2, 'sigma': 0.02}]`. Can you revise to make sure it is more precise please?

Comment: @idjaw because I want to insert the values of each parameter and key (in this case only one parameter - water), I think as an output, I don´t need it as a dict but the pure values. That´s why I expect it as: water normal {'mu':0.2, 'sigma': 0.02}. And actually I want mu and sigma also as a value, not a dict

Answer (score 1):

First, to identify where you are going wrong.

Here:

```
del ['humidity_PET', 'mc_index']
```

This is not doing what you think it is doing. The statement itself is wrong as what Python is actually interpreting is that you are trying to call `del` on a list containing those two strings. This is incorrect. As mentioned by your error:

```
SyntaxError: cannot delete literal
```

The literal in this case is a `list`. So, that explains your error message. How to correct this? You want to call `del` on your dictionary, and specify which entry you want to delete by providing the key.

You would do something like this (but, is still not what you want):

```
del json_load['humidity_PET']
del json_load['mc_index']
```

If you do this however, you are removing the entire entry under each key, so you won't even be able to access any of the data held inside each of those names!

Let's take a look at a couple other problematic areas. First, your conditional statement:

```
if 'distribution' and 'arguments' in parameter:
```

Here, you are looking for specific keywords so you can keep the values held in those keys, correct? Since each time you iterate you want to grab the same type of data, be more explicit about it, and just build what you need, and ignore the rest.

What you are looking to accomplish is:

- Take what you want
- Ignore what you don't want

How can you do this? Let's try this out.

A couple of assumptions: The `problem` data collection you are building seems to be built oddly. I believe you are trying to build a smaller version of what you currently have. If that is so, then this is not doing what you think as well:

```
problem['names'].append(parameter['name'])
```

The statement above will work assuming that a `"names"` key already exists in `problem` and that it holds a value of type `list`. Assuming that you are building something new here, chances are you do not have a pre-built dictionary already, and this has to be fully built from the data you are reading.

With the statement you have, assuming it works, you *might* end up with something like this:

```
{"Water": ["Water"]}
```

However, let us assume you have nothing, then you just need to introduce your `problem` argument before the loop as:

`problem = {}`

Your final output should then probably be something like this:

```
{
    "Water": {
        "distribution": "normal",
        "arguments": {
            "lower": 1,
            "upper": 500
        }
    }
}
```

The last thing we can look at now is how you are iterating. When you do this:

```
for parameter in json_load.values():
```

You are only looking at values. It would be helpful to look at both. Instead of `values`, use `items`, and you instead get a tuple of key value pairs, and can do this instead:

```
for key, val in json_load.items():
```

Taking all that in to consideration, you can achieve the above by modifying your code and have this:

```
# create the problem dictionary here first:
problem = {}

for key, val in json_load.items():
    # Each chunk of data in parameter you can now grab what you want and only what you want
    problem[key] = {
        "distribution": val["distribution"],
        "arguments": val["arguments"]
    }
```

When this is finished, you will have a condensed version of what you originally had that will only hold `distribution` and `arguments` for each type.

Running my code with your data, this is the final output:

```
{
  'mc_index': {
    'arguments': {
      'lower': 1, 
      'upper': 500
    },
    'distribution': 'uniform'
  },
 'tech_water': {
   'arguments': {
     'mu': 0.2, 
     'sigma': 0.02
   },
   'distribution': 'normal'
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your detailed answer! With that I can see that I haven´t described my problem well enough. I will edit it again and maybe you will see it again. 
I have already described the problem dict, I´ll post it. And I think I already can get the values inside the keys I want (names, distribution and arguments) but I want to omit/ skip 2 of my parameters.